# Wordpress wp_query displaying past post limit

Tags: php, wordpress

I just started working with WP and I'm desperately trying to create my own theme. I currently have been banging my head for a good portion of the day trying to figure out how to limit my query to just two post on my main page. For some reason it will either display all my posts or if I vary the code to have an additional value you in the array 'categories' => 'events' only one post shows up. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide :)

```
                <?php
              $args = array('posts_per_page' => 2);
              $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
              if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) :
                while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) :
                  $my_query->the_post();?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'events-content', get_post_format() ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; ?>

                    <?php alpha_paging_nav(); ?>

                <?php else : ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'events-content', 'none' ); ?>

              <?php endif; ?>

              <?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Comment: Index value for limiting the post is `posts_per_page` not `post_for_page`
and `$args` is itself an array, So you can directly pass it in `Wp_query`.

as you are new to Wordpress reffer to the Wp_query official Wordpress document will help you a lot. [https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things wrong with your Query.

The first is that you have `posts_for_page` in your arguments when it should be`posts_per_page`.

The second error is you put `$args` inside an array when you created the `new WP_Query()`. It should be:`$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );`

Comment: Hmm thanks for the help with the syntax errors, but it still is posting past the limit of 2. Any other ideas? Do I need to activate wp_query() before I have to use it?

Comment: Found the problem! It was that I had sticky posts on... Now to explore how to get sticky posts not mess up wp_query post_per_page. Thanks!

Comment: You can turn them off in your `$args` array. So your $args array should now look like this: `$args = array('posts_per_page' => 2, 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1`);`